# Using Bohr's postulate find the relation for electron velocity of lithium atom

Tags: homework-and-exercises, atomic-physics

Using Bohr's postulates derive formula for velocity of electron on 4th orbit in doubly ionized atom of lithium $_{3}Li^{7}$.

Using $$mvr=n\hbar$$
and $$\frac{mv^2}{r}=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}}\frac{Ze^4}{r^2}$$
I obtain:
$$v=\frac{Ze^4}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}\hbar}\frac{1}{n}$$

For the particular case $Z=3$ and $n=4$, but I am not sure how this double ionization affects the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bohr's model is only valid for atoms with a single electron, as it neglects any electron-electron interaction. One might think that the only atom with a single electron is hydrogen. However, ionized helium ($\mathrm{He}^+$) and doubly ionized lithium ($\mathrm{Li}^{2+}$) also fulfill this condition. (Similarly for even heavier atoms...)

So in your exercise, you need not make any changes to accommodate for the fact that the lithium is doubly ionized. It is just a requirement for the model to be applicable.

Comment: I believe you can still do bohr-sommerfeld quantization for this system, although it is not practically useful for simplifying the problem. But if you wanted to proceed that way, you would replace $mvr$ with the appropriate phase space integral and set that equal to $n \hbar$.